# Animate after popup (modal and css)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this custom modal that has an animated popup whenever it is clicked.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* transition: all 0.3s ease-out; */
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.overlay:target .popup{
  animation: popup 0.7s;
}

@keyframes popup {
  0%{
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
  50%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  60%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  70%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  80%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  90%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

One thing I can't figure out is how to animate it when it's closing.
I tried `popup:after` and  but didn't work.I also tried

```
.overlay:target .popup:after{
 animation: popup 0.7s;
}
```

but to no avail.

I want to animate the 'closing animation' the same as it animates on opening the popup. How can I do this?

Comment: Example of Animate popup 
http://dixso.github.io/custombox/

Comment: is it a problem to use jquery to accomplish this?